# how to disable exception handling code in borland c++ 5.5 compiler

Tags: c, exception, borland-c++

Sorry for my weak english

I'm using borland c++ 5.5 compiler and i like it but
one question worries me sometimes; I am writing pure c
applications with not such one c++ 'feature', but i 
compile with -P switch to force 'c++ compile' because
if I compile in c-mode I have to declare "int i"
before for loop and it is stupid. So I compile in c++
mode but I am worrying myself that that it makes
compiler to put some exception handling code
into my applications - when i look into my prog
with hex editor i see a lot of strange strings
possibly related to exception handling in .exe;
when i use -x- switch to my application it brings
no effect. I can even give a link to my progs exe

dl.dropbox.com/u/42887985/unpack%20aeroplane.zip

How can I make sure that no exception handling
(and no any other unnecessary stuff in exe becouse
i prefer to keep it tiny) is present inside?

wery much tnx for answer to that, it is important 
for me, fir

Comment: but if i compile in c-mode i must write int i befor for loop and it is not to much acceptable to do it thousand times( "int i =0; for(i=0; i<max; i++) {} ") dont you know if some switch makes possible to compile in c-mode but some modern way? second question, as to "C0W32.OBJ, CW32.LIB, and IMPORT32.LIB (initialization module, run-time library, and Windows import library)" dont  you know how can i link some versions of above but without exception handling - some things like that are stated in docs but it is not to much clear for me

Comment: fir example there is stated "C0D32.OBJ 32-bit DLL startup module (cod32w: wide-char version; cod32x: no exception handling)" - possibly this one is the reason and maybe i could change C0W.OBJ to some C0W32x.obj but i am not sure

Answer (score 2):

You can't have C++ without support for exceptions which is part of the standard. Whether or not it has much impact on you executable I cannot say.

I'd get a more modern C compiler if I were you. On Windows you should try mingw. With C99 you can declare variables wherever you like. That Borland compiler is ancient.

Comment: Non acceptable answer. BCC5.5 is my choice and it is quite good for me (light quick, no problems with winapi ogl apps at all) - and i only need the answer for my question not quasi 'advices'

Answer (score 0):

As it was noticed, you can't exclude exception handling from C++ library. But there are also  some other compiler options and other tricks, which could help you to reduce code size

1. Run-Time Type Identification or RTTI, which is used in for C++ things like `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` You can safely turn of this option if you don't use any of C++ possibilities, (defining variables inside of loops doensn't matter :-)), this could slightly reduce your executable size. RTTI Option is enabled by default and you can switch it of using -RT- switch
2. Code optimizations - if you use aggregate -O2 switch, then all optimizations are enabled, program will be compiled to be fastest as possible, but not smallest. Your should use separate switches for different optimizations. Use -Ov (Induction variables) and -Og (Optimize common subexpressions) optimization switches, which could reduce code size. Don't use -Oi switch (Inline intrinsic functions) which will increase code size
3. BCC 5.5 compiles default using 80386 instructions set (-3 switch). You can select Pentium Pro instructions set (-6 switch) which can reduce code size. MMX instructions set is also used with this options - it increases speed and also, decreases size (sorry no SSE instructions in stone age compiler ;-))
4. Use Pascal calling convention for functions. Such function will be little faster and smaller then ones using C calling convention. One disadvantage - you can't use c-style variable arguments list with this convention. You can enable this convention in your source files by using `__pascal` keyword in function definition or by providing -p switch to compiler

Comment: OKAY, tnx, but there is a switch in compiler options: -x- which is said to disable generation of code for exception handling in the app. I try tu use it but it not changes anything. I had read somewhere that could be because of linking libraries which use exception handling (those are possibly mentioned in: "By default, BCC32 starts ILINK32 with the files C0W32.OBJ, CW32.LIB, and IMPORT32.LIB (initialization module, run-time library, and Windows import library). " )

Comment: So the questions are 1) can I change those libs to some without exception handling 2) can i use c-mode compilation in some more modern way than default so i can use int i inside for()

Comment: I don't know if you compiler ships with RTL source code. If you have sources, you can try to recompile RTL (in your case it's CW32.LIB - RTL static library) without exception support, but i don't advice that. Beware, that changing anything in RTL itself can be very tricky and untrivial. I have RTL sources with C++Builder 5, which also uses bcc32 ver 5.5 and Borland says that it takes no responsibility if you recompile RTL even with default makefiles provided by Borland itself =)